# Is there a better way of writing jquery for hiding/showing div where I have two dropdowns and based on their selections, I need a reset also

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Im new to this so any help would be appreciated. I have a complex set of rules based on the selection of two dropdowns, while I have got the code working sorta, I was wondering is there a better way of writing this? Keep in mind this is the start of the code, I have multiple selects probably around 20 more and about 40 more If Else to work on, and secondly upon change of either dropdown can the other be reset?

Right now if I select from the first dropdown and then choose the second dropdown it works, but if I change the first dropdown, the second remains and does not show its div, can it be reset on change?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').on('change', function() {
    if (($(this).val() == 'Ind1') && ($(this).siblings('select').val() == 'Ins2')) {
      $('.bfcn').show();
    } else {
      $('.bfcn').hide();
    }

    if (($(this).val() == 'Ind1') && ($(this).siblings('select').val() == 'Ins1')) {
      $('.abc').show();
    } else {
      $('.abc').hide();
    }

    if (($(this).val() == 'Ind2') && ($(this).siblings('select').val() == 'Ins2')) {
      $('.cba').show();
    } else {
      $('.cba').hide();
    }

    if (($(this).val() == 'Ind2') && ($(this).siblings('select').val() == 'Ins1')) {
      $('.xyz').show();
    } else {
      $('.xyz').hide();
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select title="Select 1" id="select1">
  <option value="">Select an option</option>
  <option value="Ins1">250-500</option>
  <option value="Ins2">500-750</option>
</select>
<select title="Select 2" id="select2">
  <option value="">Select an option</option>
  <option value="Ind1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="Ind2">Option 2</option>
</select>

<p class="bfcn" style="display: none;">500-750 and Option 1</p>
<p class="abc" style="display: none;">250-500 and Option 1</p>
<p class="cba" style="display: none;">500-750 and Option 2</p>
<p class="xyz" style="display: none;">250-500 and Option 2</p>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6sfz13db/

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered adding an onchange event to your first HTML select element?  You could hook up a function that would do your reset or load up your list when it was changed.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp